# equivalent class RetrofitError in retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm looking for equivalent class [RetrofitError](http://static.javadoc.io/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.9.0/retrofit/RetrofitError.html) in retrofit 2.0

I do sync call and need status code, headers, body, etc. For async call it is easy but how to do it with async?

My code:

```
try {
Response<User> execute = call.execute();
} catch (RetroFitError e) 
{
      call.getResponse(); //Response object containing status code, headers, body, etc.
}
```